# Word Mail Merge Wizard in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I have a task where I need to perform a mail merge in Word (2016). I need to perform a normal mail merge but I need to do some custom email sending without using Outlook. I would really like to use the built-in mail merge wizard because it's familiar to our users, but I can't find a way to invoke the wizard. I found a [ShowWizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844772.aspx) method for VBA, but nothing like it for C#. Is the mail merge wizard accessible using VSTO C#? Is there a better way to accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would advise you not to use either VBA or Interop libraries. Both can only run on a machine with MS Office installed. With VBA applications you may have problems when users with different versions of Office will run them and when you will have new updates. Interop is also known to have issues in server scenarios.

For mail merging it probably makes sense to choose one from among 3rd party toolkits based on OpenXML, so they can run without MS Office (think server scenarios). You will need MS Word template documents with placeholders for data. Then you can use c# to load the data for the reports and merge the data with templates to get final documents (docx, pdf, xps or image formats). Here is the code used by one such toolkit needed for merging data from the database with the template to get a pdf document:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = DataAccess.GetCustomerById(15);
DocumentGenerator dg = new DocumentGenerator(customers);
DocumentGenerationResult result = dg.GenerateDocument("MyTemplate.docx", "MyReport.pdf");
```

On this [link](http://www.docentric.com/product/how-to-use) you can find more information and examples.

Thus far you have a way to generate mail merge documents. Now to your second problem, which is mailing these documents.

I assume that your email server is based on MS Exchange. Newer versions of MS Exchange Server expose web services which can be used from a client without the need to have Outlook installed.

There are some step-by-step tutorials, like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx, which will help you to get started. You will be able to write the application which will be in complete control of all aspects of sending mail messages. I have done a simple mail sending library for our company. It took me some time to figure out  the ins and outs of it, but now it is a set-it-and-forget-it kind of thing. It runs smoothly without any problems.

Comment: Thanks @jura for pointing me in the right direction. Are there any free openxml toolkits you would recommend? I am going to look at the OpenXML SDK found on Nuget. It looks like it has some tools for converting from DOCX to HTML and will pull data from XLSX, both of which I will need.

Comment: OpenXML SDK makes sense if you have to do simple document manipulation. I had to solve complex document merging with complex templates. I had very limited time to achieve that, so I used 3rd party library.